# Google Sites + Maps Javascript API + HTML5 Geolocation

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to implement a map with a route that has a waypoint and a dynamic origin within a Google Site. I'd like to set the origin based on the user's location who access the Google Sites and I'm using the HTML5 Geolocation API to retrieve the user's geolocation. However, I'm not able to retrieve properly the user's geolocation.

Here you will find the code I'm currently implementing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>PATH A</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }

      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <script>    
    function initMap() {
        const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        const directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
          zoom: 8,
          center: { lat: 37.132, lng: 13.869 },
        });
        directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
        
        const onChangeHandler = function () {
          calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer);
        };
        
        window.onload = onChangeHandler;
    }
    
    function setPosition(position){
        currentOrigin = {};
        currentOrigin.lat = position.coords.latitude;
        currentOrigin.lng = position.coord.longitude;
    }
    
    function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer){
    let currentOrigin = new google.maps.LatLng(37.081, 14.214);
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setPosition);
        } else {
          // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
              console.log("Browser does not support geolocation");
        }
        const waypts = [];
        waypts.push({
            location: { lat: 37.261, lng: 13.588},
            stopover: true
        });
        directionsService.route({
            origin: currentOrigin,
            destination: {
             lat: 37.314 , lng: 13.576
            },
            optimizeWaypoints: false,
            waypoints: waypts,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        }, (response, status) => {
            if(status === "OK" && response) {
                directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
            } else {
                console.log("An error occurred: " + status);
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <!-- Async script executes immediately and must be after any DOM elements used in callback. -->
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=*********&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly"
      async
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is the Geolocation API somehow blocked by the Google Sites' policies? If so, is there any other way to set up a dynamic origin? The desired solution is to have a map on the site that has a route with a specific waypoint.

Thanks in advance for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

So a couple of things first I think you have a typo in your setPosition callback function the longitude should be `position.coords.longitude` . Also you need to set the center of the google maps object when the navigator returns a lat and lng. Right now currentOrigin is out of scope of the map and never is able to update. One thing you could possibly try is passing a reference of your map object to calculateAndDisplayRoute and setting the map's location in the setPosition callback.
Try this:

```
function initMap() {
    const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    const directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      zoom: 8,
      center: { lat: 37.132, lng: 13.869 },
    });
    directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
    
    const onChangeHandler = function () {
      calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer, map);
    };
    
    window.onload = onChangeHandler;
}

function setPosition(position, map){
    currentOrigin = {};
    map.setCenter({ lat : position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude });
}

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer, map){
let currentOrigin = new google.maps.LatLng(37.081, 14.214);
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
         setPosition(position, map);
     });
    } else {
      // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
          console.log("Browser does not support geolocation");
    }
    const waypts = [];
    waypts.push({
        location: { lat: 37.261, lng: 13.588},
        stopover: true
    });
    directionsService.route({
        origin: currentOrigin,
        destination: {
         lat: 37.314 , lng: 13.576
        },
        optimizeWaypoints: false,
        waypoints: waypts,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    }, (response, status) => {
        if(status === "OK" && response) {
            directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
        } else {
            console.log("An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });
}
```

I passed the map object through to the callback so that setCenter could be called on the navigators position.